# Validating a field that does not exist in the database

Tags: cakephp

Can i model validate a field that dose not exist in the database.   It's not working for the following code

Model

```
'agree' => array(
    'comparison' => array(
            'rule' => array('comparison', 'equal to', 1),
            'message' => 'Accept the Proposal',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update'  operations 
    ), 
),
```

.
view

```
<div class="input checkbox">
<input type="hidden" name="data[Season][agree]" id="SeasonAgree_" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Season][agree]" value="1" id="SeasonAgree">
<label for="SeasonAgree"></label> Seasons Proposal displayed is correct
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate a field which is not in the database.
e.g. In a register form you can validate "I accept user terms" field and don't save this value on the database.

In your code you're validating "accept" instead "agree". In fact, you have two inputs with the same name (`"data[Season][agree]"`), it could be a problem.

Comment: It's not a problem, because this covers the case when the checkbox is not checked. If the first hidden field doesn't exist, then if the checkbox is disabled it's not present in the _POST and it could lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nik. I've checked one of my cakephp forms with checkbox fields and I've noticed cakephp creates that hidden field. I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

Validating a field which is not in the model is possible. Your mistake is that in the model you validating "accept" while in the view the field is called "agree".